# MYSQL: Left Joining only the first row or select distinct

Tags: mysql, left-join

I'm trying to do left join on several tables. However, it's showing all the left join table results. The master table would be 'a' but it's showing duplicates id because its id exist several times on other tables. How can I choose only the first row on the other tables? or select the distinct results on the table 'a' ? Here's my SQL

```
SELECT a.adsId, a.adsName, a.adsUrl, a.sourceFileName, c.userName, d.preferenceId, e.ppv FROM y5ads_new.ads_source a 
                INNER JOIN y5ads_new.campaign b ON a.campaignId=b.campaignId 
                INNER JOIN y5ads_new.system_member c ON b.createdBy=c.memberId
                INNER JOIN y5ads_new.ads_preference d ON a.adsId=d.adsId
                INNER JOIN y5ads_new.ads_rates e ON a.adsId=e.adsId
                WHERE a.status='2' AND a.deleted='False' AND CURDATE() BETWEEN a.startDate and a.endDate 
                AND b.status='2' AND b.deleted='False' AND CURDATE() BETWEEN b.startDate and b.endDate 
                AND d.deleted='False' AND CURDATE() BETWEEN d.startDate and d.endDate 
                AND e.is_active='1' AND CURDATE() BETWEEN e.startDate and e.endDate 
                ORDER BY a.adsId DESC, d.preferenceId DESC, e.id DESC
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your IDs distinct and use LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT a.adsId, a.adsName, a.adsUrl, a.sourceFileName, c.userName, d.preferenceId, e.ppv 
FROM y5ads_new.ads_source AS a 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT campaignId as campaignId FROM y5ads_new.campaign) AS b 
ON a.campaignId=b.campaignId 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT memberId AS memberId, userName FROM y5ads_new.system_member) AS c 
ON b.createdBy=c.memberId
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT adsId AS adsId, preferenceId FROM y5ads_new.ads_preference) AS d 
ON a.adsId=d.adsId
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT adsId AS adsId, ppv FROM y5ads_new.ads_rates) AS e 
ON a.adsId=e.adsId
WHERE ...
```

Comment: omg, I can't see the difference but it works... can I have the previous one to compare or can you tell me what went wrong ?

Comment: and btw, if I add b.example on the select statement, I got the same error.... I guess something wrong on b

Comment: Nevermind, I got it... just have to add the columns if I want to select it to the select distinct statement... Thanks